# HTML templating

Tags: html, templates

I'm wondering if it would be possible to setup some sort of HTML templating system, basically I have 3 different files:
 - header.html
 - footer.html
 - landing.html (landing.html is the main template that contains the page)

Essentially I only want people to edit landing.html, and when they open this file, header.html and footer.html should be inserted into this file.

So header.html would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
```

footer.html would be

```
</body>
</html>
```

and landing.html would contain all html to show a page, but all of this should be done without any form of pre-processing or generators, it could be done with javascript, but I want people to just open landing.html and have the header and footer inserted into it.

Would something like this be possible somehow?

Comment: you could use php and use the include() function

Comment: @theDazzler I considered that, but the people that will be opening the landing.html won't have a local server running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use little jQuery for this,

In **landing.html**:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var header;
    $.get('header.html', function(data){
    header= data;
    $("body").prepend(header);
});
var footer;
    $.get('footer.html', function(data){
    footer= data;
    $("body").append(footer);
});

});
```

Using above code you can request for **header.html** and **footer.html** pages residing in the same root. But i dont think this is a proper way of templating.

Comment: The thing is that once you open landing.html, the browser automatically creates the <head> and <body> tags, which are in the header.html